# Use HiDPI rendering (Retina) in an OpenGL Screensaver

Tags: objective-c, opengl, xcode4.5, retina-display, screensaver

For several years now I've been using the Noof screensaver ported to Mac OS X by Chris:

[Skoroworld](http://www.skoroworld.com/~chrish/osx/)

I have it running fine under 10.8 and have already updated the project with high resolution artwork and some other tweaks to the prefs panel to get things working however I cannot seem to figure out how to enable it to use the higher resolution rendering instead of the pixel-doubled stuff on a Retina display. The code below seems to be drawing the window at 2880x1800 but it's still pixel doubled.

I've pasted what I think are the relevant parts of the code.

---

### CODE

```
static void
reshape_noof(int w, int h)
{
     glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 if (w <= h) {
      wd = 1.0;
      ht = (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w;
      glOrtho(0.0, 1.0,
                0.0, 1.0 * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w,
                -16.0, 4.0);
 } else {
      wd = (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h;
      ht = 1.0;
      glOrtho(0.0, 1.0 * (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h,
                0.0, 1.0,
                -16.0, 4.0);
 }
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();

 glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

### SNIP

```
// ScreenSaverView methods

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
if (self) {
      [self loadSettings];
    [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1.0/delay];

      NSRect newFrame = frame;
      newFrame.origin.x = 0.0;
      newFrame.origin.y = 0.0;

      glView = [[NSOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame pixelFormat:[NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat]];
    if( glView ) {
        [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
           [self addSubview:glView];
      }
 }

return self;
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
[super startAnimation];

 // Load our settings
 [self loadSettings];

 // Turn off the cursor; this doesn't always seem to happen on Tiger. :-(
 if( ![self isPreview] ) [NSCursor hide];

 firstRun = YES;

 // Prepare OpenGL.
 [[glView openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
[self setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface:YES];
[self convertRectToBacking:[self bounds]];
// Get view dimensions in pixels
NSRect backingBounds = [self convertRectToBacking:[self bounds]];

GLsizei backingPixelWidth  = (GLsizei)(backingBounds.size.width),
backingPixelHeight = (GLsizei)(backingBounds.size.height);
 float w = backingPixelWidth;
 float h = backingPixelHeight;
 reshape_noof( w, h );

 // from init_noof
 glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
 glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < N_SHAPES; i++)
      initshapes(i);

 //[self animateOneFrame];
 glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
 glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
 glFlush();
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
 // Turn on the cursor.
 if( ![self isPreview] ) [NSCursor unhide];

[super stopAnimation];
}

- (void)animateOneFrame
{
 int i;

 if( firstRun ) {
      // Make **** sure our view port is correct.
    [self setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface:YES];
    [self convertRectToBacking:[self bounds]];
    // Get view dimensions in pixels
    NSRect backingBounds = [self convertRectToBacking:[self bounds]];

    GLsizei backingPixelWidth  = (GLsizei)(backingBounds.size.width),
    backingPixelHeight = (GLsizei)(backingBounds.size.height);

    // Set viewport
      reshape_noof( backingPixelWidth, backingPixelHeight );
      firstRun = NO;
 }

 gravity( -2.0 );
 for( i = 0; i < N_SHAPES; i++ ) {
      motionUpdate( i );
      colorUpdate( i );
      drawleaf( i );
 }

 glFinish();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would move the line `[self setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface:YES];` to right after you initialized the `NSOpenGLView`

```
glView = [[NSOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame pixelFormat:[NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat]];
[glView setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface:YES];
```

At least that's how I did my screensaver and it seems to work.